# Error When Trying to Run Slope Analysis Script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, slope, error-000875

I have written a script which is supposed to loop through all the rasters in a folder and perform a slope analysis on each raster and save the results in another folder.

I keep getting the following error:

> < type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: ERROR 000875: Output raster:
>   C:\Slope_Outputs\burd_25m_dem_slope's workspace is an invalid output
>   workspace.

Here's my code:

```
class LicenseError(Exception):
    pass

# Set desktop license used to ArcView
#
import arcview
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

try:
    if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    else:
        # Raise a custom exception
        raise LicenseError

except LicenseError:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Spatial Analyst license is unavailable")
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)

from arcpy.sa import *

originLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
slopeMeasurement = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
destinationLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.env.workspace = originLocation

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*")

for raster in rasterList:
    finalDestination = destinationLocation+"\\"+raster+"_slope"
    arcpy.AddMessage(finalDestination)
    outSlope=arcpy.sa.Slope(raster, slopeMeasurement)
    arcpy.AddMessage(outSlope)
    outSlope.save(finalDestination)
```

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found on [this page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00590000001q000000) that the maximum raster name length is 13 characters.  I have modified my code to take the first 7 characters of the input raster name and add "_slope" at the end of it.

This works for now, but I think I will modify my code to write to a different file format instead of ESRI GRID or possibly a geodatabase instead.

Comment: someone told me before that, the file name length should be 8, 11 or 13. He was not sure. 11 length worked for me. So, I told you to keep the name length less or equal 11. thanks for sharing the link :)

Comment: How about adding `"_slope.tif"` at the end? GeoTIFFs are fantastic, with no funny name length limitations.

Answer (score 3):

try changing the workspace name to this C:\Slope_Outputs\burd_25m_dem_slopes. I think the problem might be that you are using unsupported characters in your workspace name. Maybe this [post for ESRI](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23087) will be helpful

Comment: There are no unsupported characters in the workspace name.  The apostrophe after 'slope' was added by ArcGIS in displaying the error.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about it. But Try those:

1. Try change the drive.
2. Try keep the raster name length less than or equal 11.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the "\" is causing problems. Try the following:

```
import os # add this in with your other imports at top of code
finalDestination = destinationLocation + os.sep + raster + "_slope"
```